# How to upload microsoft word and pdf files using php form with postgresql server

Tags: php, postgresql, file-upload

I am novice so i realy appreciate the favour you guys will do with me.
Here i want to make upload cv function in my own website so kindly if anyone has the code ready or can tell me what to do ? i will be very thankful.

waiting for your responses

Answer (score 1):

It is a very generic question, but if you are a total novice here are some tips of the steps required. You can search for tutorials on each of these:

1) Set up a form that allows file uploads

2) handle file upload in PHP

3) create a database record with the key parameters of the file, such as name, description, unique id

4) How to rename the file, so its file name on the server file system is unique (assuming you want to allow uploading the same file name multiple times)

5) save the file to disk

6) create a screen that displays a table of files previously uploaded

7) stream  the file from disk, when clicked on the file name, sending the original file name

8) Add a user interface to the list of files to delete a file - and make sure it is protected against CSRF attacks

9) delete a specific file from the list, erase the database record and ensure the file is not stored on the web server anymore.

Comment: i understood some things but if you have some code to show me which should be working too then it will be good for me :)